# spring-webmvc.jar does not come with the Spring Framework 3.0.5 download

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

When I download the Spring Framework (Latest GA release: 3.0.5.RELEASE) from the [download page at springsource.org](http://www.springsource.org/download), the ZIP file does not contain spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, or anything like it.  Am I missing something here?

The actual ZIP file is at: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE.zip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the "web.servlet" jar instead of "spring-webmvc". I'm not sure exactly how or when it changed, but at least the [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar) jar has exactly the same content as the org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar from the zip file.